# Qt-application only works correctly if started from the command line

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I made a pretty simple application with Qt Creator on Ubuntu 12.04. The application reads an xml-file and shows a couple of images. But when I try to start the application by double clicking the icon on a different machine (running Lubuntu), the images are not shown, and the xml-file is not read. The application does work properly when it is started from the command line by typing ./App.

Why does it behave like this and how do I fix it?

**edit**: The method that reads the xml:

```
QDomDocument doc("document");
QString path = "datastorage.xml"; // xml is in same directory as the executable
QFile xmlFile(path);

if (!xmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    throw QString("Error with XML: Could not open file " + path);
if (!doc.setContent(&xmlFile)) {
    xmlFile.close();
    throw QString("Error with XML: Could not set QDomDocument content from " + path);
}
xmlFile.close();
QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
return root;
```

Comment: Seems to be a path problem. Could you post the code where you open the xml file?

Comment: What do you mean "I try to start the application from the desktop executable on a different machine"?

Comment: @KalebPederson: I moved the files to another machine where it is intended to be used, and tried to start it by double clicking the application icon. So it was NOT a desktop shortcut, I chose my words poorly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply you are using relative paths to read files and those paths are always relative to "working directory". If you're launching your app from console, and all required files are within app directory then everything works. When launching from desktop working directory may be different. Just prepend QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() to all paths you're using.

Comment: This did the trick, however I don't see how the relative paths would have messed it up, as it wasn't actually started from the desktop (I clarified the question regarding that), but from the icon in the application's directory. Worked, none the less.

Comment: Consider using a [resource](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/resources.html) file, rather than building paths yourself.

Comment: Well it messed up because of working directory. Launching from any kind of "shortcut" will change your working directory. Try launching your app from directory above your app. It won't work either.